# Apache Camel FTP filefilter

Tags: java, apache-camel, filefilter, camel-ftp

How I can configurate my filefilter without this

```
<bean id="#myFilter" class="com.mycompany.Myfilter"/>,
```

just use JAVA

Comment: @ClausIbsent i try use Apache Camel for download files between many days and insert to SQL, but ftp server have a lot of other files. I want use filefilter for matches file by filename, filename content date like 13_07_2016.

Comment: See the unit tests of camel-ftp where there are some that uses a file filter: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-ftp/src/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a class that implements GenericFileFilter and then add to the main Camel

```
  main.bind("ftpProcessor",new FtpProcessor());
```